# Data is only loading on reload?

Tags: angularjs

Im getting data from factory. after request im defining some properties.

```
http.get( 'app/propertyType/get.php').then(function (response) 
             {

            if (response.data) {
                var data = response.data;                   

                dataFactory.propertyTypes = angular.extend({
                    asArray: data
                }
                });
            }
        });
 getPropertyTypes: function () {
                return this.propertyTypes;
            }
```

Thats how im getting in controller..

```
       $scope.propertyTypes = DataFactory.getPropertyTypes();
        $scope.$watch(function () {
            return DataFactory.getPropertyTypes();
        }, function (newValue) {
            if (newValue) {
                $scope.propertyTypes = newValue;
            }
        });
```

so it needs a reload to successfully load data..how to solve this problem? whenever i change the route it should be already loaded in page.

Comment: You could use the `resolve`-function in your route configuration. Route resolve accepts promises, so the page only loads once the promise has resolved.

Answer (score 0):

To reload the state on any condition , you can use `$state.reload();`

Comment: thats the problem..i dont want to reload..it should load the data when route loads

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `ui.router` module, to load smth before entering the route you can use `resolve` block in the state definition.
Ex:

```
$stateProvider.state('state1', {
    controller:'controller',
    templateUrl:'url',
    resolve: function(DataFactory){
        DataFactory.getPropertyTypes();
    }
})
```

Also to make this work you should return `promise` object from `DataFactory.getPropertyTypes()`

*EDIT*: U can also use `resolve` in `ngRoute` routes definition. [Here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx) you can read details on how to do that.

Comment: Im using routeProvider.

Comment: @waseemak , see my edit. You can also use `resolve` block in `routeProvider.when()` configuration

Comment: is there anyway to make changes in controller to solve this issue?

Comment: @waseemak, if you want data to be available on controller instantiation then no, Otherwise you can handle `promise` in the controller and do smth like this: `DataFactory.getPropertyTypes().then(function(data){ $scope.propertyTypes = data});` in that way you dont need to `watch` but you should remember that `$scope.propertyTypes` will be populated in future and not rely on it in other code pieces.